# Wiring a Junction Box: 1 source in, 2 sources out

Tags: electrical, junction-box

I have an existing junction box and currently 1 source from the basement going in, and one source coming out and that goes to a wall switch.

If I want to connect a second wire to come from that junction box, would I just attach all hot and all neutral wires together in the box? In my head it sounds like this wouldn't be a complete loop, but maybe I am just overthinking it.

So one source going into the box and then two wires coming out of it, each going to their own box in the walls below.

Anyone have a diagram for this? Thank you!

Comment: When you say "wire" in the first context, you mean "cable"... For instance NM cable has 2-4 wires in it plus a bare ground wire.  It's a lot easier to understand that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you would tie the hots together, the neutrals together, and the grounds together. Below is an image of the inside of the box for reference.

[image: Wiring image]

And here is a wiring diagram as requested. The main line from your breaker comes in at the top of the diagram and enters the box. It is then tied off and sent to the left to your always hot load or other switch and also to the right towards the existing switch and load. (Black is hot, gray is neutral, orange blobs are wire nuts, and grounds are not shown for simplicity)

[image: Wiring diagram]

I've also included a more clear cut version of the diagram so that you can see the flow of power.

Comment: Okay thank you, that was an image I was looking at earlier. I just wanted to make sure that if the two wires (connected together with the source) going to the seperate gang boxes, wouldnt cause issues. In this case they are just sharing power correct?   I look forward to your image.

Comment: And the wires going to the top part of the image can have the same type of loop? Adding in a switch and bulb?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, they are sharing power. They are in 'parallel' with each other where the power is divided between the two.

Comment: And yes. The top wires on my diagram are where the power is being brought in from the breaker and so keeping with it, the left side would go to the new loop, but yes you can branch off and create it's own loop.

Comment: In the top picture, why isn't ground coming from the breaker box? Also, if you are connecting grounding cable (bare copper / green) to breaker box, is it still necessary to hook it to junction box? What is the JB is plastic and not metal?

Comment: @cryptic0 I left the grounds off to make it easier to understand - more lines would make it more confusing. But yes, a ground wire would be ran with every set of conductors and it is necessary to connect to the junction box/switch/light if they have a ground terminal or are metal. If the JB is plastic, you still have to take the ground through to the other items and so it'd just be wirenutted together in the box, but not screwed down.